# EF Core 3.1 Add Custom Column to Migration History Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core-3.1

This is how we have been adding the custom column Applied to migration history table.

```
public class MigrationHistoryRepository : SqlServerHistoryRepository
    {
        public MigrationHistoryRepository(
            HistoryRepositoryDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies)
        {
        }

    protected override void ConfigureTable(EntityTypeBuilder<HistoryRow> history)
    {
        base.ConfigureTable(history);
        history.Property<DateTime>("Applied").HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

But now it shows a warning on building after I upgraded EF Core from 2.2 to 3.1.

This is the warning:

> *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Migrations.Internal.SqlServerHistoryRepository is an internal API that supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and not subject to the same compatibility standards as public APIs. It may be changed or removed without notice in any release.*

I am looking for good alternate ways to add custom columns in EF Core 3.1, so I don't get any warnings like above.